# What mean [^>] in regex preg php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Example code:

```
<?php
$html = <<< html
<p><a href="http://www.google.com" title="10">google.com</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.cade.com" title="11">cade.com</a></p>
html;

echo preg_replace('#<p><a href\="([^>]+)" title="([^>]+)">([^>]+)</a></p>#','<p>$1 - $2</p>',$html);
?>
```

It works fine but i would like to know what `[^>]` means. I know that

- `+` = 1 or more;
- `()` = subpatterns;

But I don't know about `^>`

Comment: Please mark an answer that has helped you as accepted, you have not done this for any of your questions.

Answer (score 3):

It means any character other than `>`

Answer (score 2):

`^`, when placed at the start of a [character class](http://ca.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) (`[`) means any character EXCEPT what's in the class.

In your code, that would mean it would match any character except `>`.

Comment: it will match all characters (.+) isn't?

Comment: No, . matches any character. [^] matches any character but the characters following the ^ before the ].

[^aiu] would match any character except a or i or u
[^a-f] would match any character except a, b, c, d, e, f
[^.] would match any character except .

Answer (score 1):

It means that it should match any other character than `>`. It also means that the person that wrote this code and tried to parse HTML with regex didn't read [the Bible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and will very soon regret it.

Answer (score 1):

It means any character apart from `>`.

(Side note: it is not usually a good idea to use regex to parse HTML.)

Comment: Agreed: This is because HTML is not a regular language ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not ). For small limited input it can be OK but for large complex non-standard data it will break and leave you crying. +1

Answer (score 1):

`[^>]` means a set of characters including all characters but `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have it in the [PHP documentation for PCRE regex syntax](http://es.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

First, you have a [list of meta-characters](http://es.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php). You can check there to find the meaning of characters in regexes.

Concerning your question we find that:

- The [ sign starts a [character class](http://es.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) definition, finished by ].
- The use of ^ as the first character of a character class negates the character class.
- > isn't a meta-character.

So, [^>] is any character that isn't >